# Joomla virtuemart theme modification

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I am presently working on a Joomla website having ecommerce functionality. I am a beginner in joomla. I need to modify my virtuemart theme according to my own css and html. How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Simply head into your_joomla_directory/components/com_virtuemart/themes/your_theme_folder/theme.css

theme.css edits virutemart elements only, you may also have to edit your main template css file to get the full desired effect.